# Why not design classical electron theory in the vacuum gauge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, gauge-invariance

The Lienard-Wiechert potentials (published 1898-1900) are used to determine the field strength tensor of a classical (point) electron in arbitrary motion.  If we perform a gauge transformation on the potentials via $$ A^\nu_{lw} \longrightarrow A^\nu_{lw} + \partial^\nu\phi $$ the fields are unchanged. One can surmise that there is no point in using any other set potentials as they produce extraneous terms not necessary for calculating the field strength tensor.

However, suppose we choose the scalar field $\phi = -e\ln\rho$.  In this simple equation $\rho$ is the scalar invariant given by $\rho=R^\nu\beta_\nu$, and $R^\nu$ is the vector from the retarded position of the charge to the present time point where the field is to be evaluated. Then $$\partial^\nu\phi = -A^\nu_{lw} +A^\nu_v + A^\nu_a $$ and the new potentials are given by $$A^\nu_v =\frac{eR^\nu}{\rho^2} \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad A^\nu_a = -a^\lambda R_\lambda A^\nu_v$$
The merits of this gauge transformation become apparent when calculating the field strength tensor  where the velocity and acceleration fields are now associated with individual components of the potentials $$F^{\mu\nu}_v = [\partial^\mu, A^\nu_v] \qquad \mbox{and} \qquad F^{\mu\nu}_a = [\partial^\mu, A^\nu_a]$$

The new set of potentials can be written $$A^\nu_{total} = (1-a^\lambda R_\lambda)A $$ and will have a clear advantage over the Lienard-Wiechert potentials in many scenarios. Why not design classical electron theory in the vacuum gauge ?